# Let $I$ ideal of $\mathcal{O}(D)$ then $fg\in I\Rightarrow f(z)g(z)(z-z_0)^{-k}\in I$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the ring $\mathcal{O}(D)$ of holomorphic functions on the open subset $D\subseteq\Bbb C$.

Let then consider an ideal $I\unlhd \mathcal{O}(D)$ s.t. $\bigcap_{f\in I,f\neq0}f^{-1}(0)=\emptyset$.

Let $z_0\in D$; then if $f,g\in \mathcal{O}(D)$ are two functions such that $z_0$ is the only zero of $f$ in $D$ and $fg\in I$, I must to prove that $f(z)g(z)(z-z_0)^{-k}\in I$ for all $0\le k\le m$ where $m=\text{ord}_{z_0}f$.

I started writing $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mh(z)$, where $h$ a never vanishing function in $\mathcal{O}(D)$, but I can't get the result.

Can you give me some hint please?

Comment: $g$ doesn't belong to $I$; what we know is that $fg\in I$.

Comment: You can get rid of $h(z)$, since it is an invertible element of the ring. Moreover, it is enough to prove this result for $k=m$. So, you have to show that, provided $g(z)(z-z_0)^m \in I$, you have $g \in I$. If $I$ is a prime ideal, this is obvious (because $(z-z_0) \notin I$), but then I have no ideas for the general case.

Comment: It seems that the problem needs some correction. Let $z_0$ and $z_1$ be two points on $D$, and  $I$ an ideal generated by $z-z_0$ and $z-z_1$. If $f=z-z_0$ and $g=1$, then $fg\in I$ but $f(z)g(z)(z-z_0)^{-1}=1\not\in I$.

Comment: @Spark: many thanks.
But you will agree with me in saying it is strange, since it is an exercise my teacher gives every year.